# Don't receive Trello Webhook response

Tags: javascript, next.js, trello

I have build an api-function for a trello webhook.

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method == "POST") {
    value = req.body;
    res.status(200).json("Ok");
    initalBoardID = value.model.id;
    value = value.action;
    type = value.type;
    translationKey = value.display.translationKey;
    if (
      type == "addMemberToCard" &&
      translationKey == "action_member_joined_card"
    ) {
      member = value.display.entities.member.id;
      createCard();
    }
  } else {
    res.status(200).json("Function works");
  }
}
```

If I use Postman this function works fine. But Trello doesn't send any webhook tho this function.

The URL has an SSL certificate and an https protocol.

How can I update this function that Trello send a webhook tho this function?

Comment: You should trying to find a log in Trello. May it depends to CORS or anything else

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find any error message in the console. Do you have any other idea what could be the problem?

Comment: You can at least add log something at first and be sure that this handler call or not. @Max also you can google to find Trello webhook logs.